# Is it possible to programmatically resize the terminal/file explorer panels?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to resize the terminal panel and the file explorer. Is there an API or something for it?

Thanks.

Comment: an API? You want to be able to resize programatically from an extension?

Comment: Yeah, through an extension